# How to use execute mysqldiff utilities in command line?

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I have two versions of my database. The n and n+1 version. I want to know the difference between the two version. I have downloaded the archive on the link [mysqldiff utility](https://github.com/aspiers/mysqldiff)

I unzip my archive and went in the bin directory, then i type mysqldiff -help. But at my surprise, i have the following message. mysqldif is not recognozed as  command line. Is there any way to install it ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try "./mysqldiff" or "perl mysqldiff"?  Most people path's don't (and shouldn't!!) contain the current working directory.

Comment: I've tried ./mysqldiff mysqldiff is not recognize and perl mysqldiff try to compile the module but it's failed : Can't locate MySQL/Diff.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/PROGRAMMING/tools/MySQL-Diff-0.43/bin C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at mysqldiff line 111.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at mysqldiff line 111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you read the INSTALL file in the link you gave, it doesn't say to download the archive, it says to install via CPAN.

However, I'm not sure why you'd use a CPAN module or some random Github archive when MySQL distributes a mysqldiff.exe [1] tool itself.

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of that ancient CPAN module and I don't really maintain it any more.  It looks like [another `mysqldiff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldiff.html) is offered in the [MySQL Utilities suite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-utilities.html) which [seems to be maintained](https://launchpad.net/mysql-utilities/+series) (here's a [github clone](https://github.com/dannykopping/mysql-utilities)) and also a lot more sophisticated, so I'd recommend trying that.